# Django generate bar code and download via browser

Tags: django, download, barcode

I am able to generate the bar code and save the image file in the root folder using this library [python-barcode](https://pypi.org/project/python-barcode/).
Now I am trying to generate the bar code image and download via browser as HttpResponse

Here are my tryouts,

```
import barcode

from django.http import HttpResponse

def download_bar_code(request):
    ean = barcode.get('upc', '123456789102', writer=ImageWriter())
    ean.save('filename')
    image = ean.render() # Returns PIL image class
    # <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=523x280 at 0x7FAE2B471320>
    return HttpResponse(image, content_type="image/png")
```

Here the image file is saving in the root folder, but not downloading via a browser.
I am not able to find the solution for this, I request you to please suggest me some solution to solve this, it would be very grateful for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: download means ?

Comment: Download /save the image file via browser @NishantNawarkhede

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like

```
response = HttpResponse(mimetype="image/png")
image.save(response, "PNG")
return response
```

The response is a stream similar to a file, so you can write to that instead of saving it to file.

Also, I think you can skip `ean.save('filename')` but I'm not 100% sure as I've never used that library.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, with little modification, it works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(req):
    response = HttpResponse(image, content_type="image/png")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=file_name.png'
    return response
```

Comment: Sorry, this code is not working. thanks for your effort